# /etc/sudoers shows no privileges, yet `sudo --list` reports ALL privileges

Tags: sudo

**tl;dr** `/etc/sudoers` and `groups` implies no sudo privileges. Yet `sudo --list` reports `ALL` sudo privileges.  Why the difference?

### Background

On an Ubuntu 18 desktop, file `/etc/sudoers` has

```
Defaults !visiblepw
Defaults always_set_home
Defaults secure_path="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
Defaults env_reset
Defaults env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

root ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL

%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

`groups` reports (*run as user `user1`*)

```
user group1 group2 ...
```

(*there is a long list of specialized groups set by the host Administrator, none of which are `sudo` or `root`*)

`sudo --list` reports (*run as user `user1`*)

```
Matching Defaults entries for user1 on host1:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL
    PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER
    LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

User user1 may run the following commands on host1:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

### Inconsistent Privileges?

File `/etc/sudoers` and current `groups` would imply that my user `user1` has no sudo access.  User `user1` is not in the group `sudo` or group `root`.
**Yet `sudo --list` reports `user1` has privilege `(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`!**

What file or service or mis-understanding is happening such that `user1` has sudo privilege `ALL`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski mentioned in an Answer Comment, I had looked past the line `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` within the `/etc/sudoers` file.  I thought this line was a comment because of the leading `#` character.  Unexpectedly,`#includedir` is the syntax for including directories.  @roaima Answer suggested looking at files within the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` that provides the extra configuration to allow `user1` the full access you're seeking.

Comment: Indeed!  `sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/group1` has `%group1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`.

Comment: @James In `sudoers` you probably have `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d/`. This is *not* a comment. It looks like some directive that has been commented out, but in fact `#includedir` (with leading `#`) is a directive. IMO very bad design.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @KamilMaciorowski I hastily presumed `#includedir ...` was a commented line. I entirely forgot about this unexpected quirk of the sudoers file format. I will tweak the question.